# How to solve a polynomial with decimal degrees in Scilab?

Tags: decimal, scilab, polynomials, degrees

I'm trying to program in Scilab a polynomial with decimals degrees like this :
3*x^2.5 + 5*x^7.5;

It is easy to write a polynomial with integers degrees in Scilab. The method is the following :
v =[-2-5*%x+%x^2];
disp("Result is " + pol2str(v)); // it writes : -2 -5*x + x^2";

But if I write this code, it doesn't work anymore:
v =[-2-5*%x^1.5+%x^2.5]; // I have an error in the console of Scilab, and I don't get this result expected : -2 -5*x^1.5 + x^2.5.

I have tried to write a polynomial by multplying with a sqrt, but I have some difficulties.

My question is how can we define a polynomial with decimals degrees in Scilab ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try brackets? -2-5*%x^(1.5)+%x^(2.5)

Comment: Wikipedia: In mathematics, a polynomial is an expression consisting of variables (also called indeterminates) and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative *integer* exponentiation of variables.

Comment: @GreyFairer, I tried to test with brackets. But, when I executed the code the answer in the console was : "Invalid exponent: integer expected." It seems it doesn't work. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Stéphane Mottelet, exactly this is why my code doesn't work. So, I have to find another method to write correctly the polynomial equation. Thank you very much.

Comment: In fact you want to solve it right ? In this case please change the title, e.g. "How to solve a polynomial with decimal degrees in Scilab", then we will see how to.

Comment: Exactly @StéphaneMottelet, thank you for your notice.

Comment: If your exponents are rationals then it is always possible to proceed by using two steps: first rewrite your polynomial p(x)=P(X) with X=x^(1/q) as undeterminate where q is the least common multiple of the denominators of each exponent. I let you handle the second step...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find the roots for your example. Just adapt the values of coefficients in `a` and exponents in `expo` for other cases:

```
a = [3 5];
expo = [2.5,7.5];
[n,d] = rat(expo);
q = lcm(d);
coef(expo*q+1) = a;
P = poly(coef,'X','coeff');
theRoots = roots(P).^q;

// eval the function at roots
for i = 1:length(theRoots)
    disp(abs(sum(a.*theRoots(i).^expo)))
end
```

see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291208/number-of-roots-of-a-polynomial-of-non-integer-degree